# The printf method won't work

Tags: java, printf

This is the second time I've tried to use the `PrintWriter#printf` method, and I get this error message:

> The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the argument (String, String)

The code I'm using has two classes.

This is the first class:

```
class apples4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    tuna4 tuna4Object = new tuna4("Kelsey");
        tuna4Object.saying();
    }
}
```

This is the second class:

```
public class tuna4 {
    private String girlName;

    public tuna4(String name) {
        girlName=name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        girlName=name;  
    }

    public String getName() {
        return girlName;
    }

    public void saying(){
        System.out.printf("Your first girlfriend was %s\n", getName() );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I downloaded java about two weeks ago. i think it's 1.8

Comment: Java 6, 7 or 8 should work which suggests you are not using those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Check your compliance level...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`PrintStream#printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method is available since Java SE 5. Looks like your code is being compiled/evaluated by Java 4 or prior.

Review your JDK installation and/or your IDE settings about how it is compiling/evaluating your code.

---

By the way, if using Eclipse and Java 8, Eclipse needs a plugin to recognize Java 8 applications, so by default the evaluator will downgrade your project to Java 1.4. This happened to me and I solved it by [installing an update in Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/). Eclipse Luna (latest Eclipse version)says that it supports Java 8, but didn't work for me (not sure if I followed the right steps or did something wrong, but went back to Kepler and works fine).

Comment: I've got Java version 1.8. I just tried out 1.5 and that didn't work either. How do i check how it's compiling the code?

Comment: @zyzz Depends on your IDE, you'll have to tell us which one you're using.

Comment: I'm guessing that since `PrintStream#printf` has a var args `Object` parameter, and var args were introduced in Java 1.5, that Java 1.4 would have used an `Object[]`, and having your IDE use a Java 1.4 compiler would then explain the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound weird, but you can cast the return value of your getName() method to Object:

```
System.out.printf("Your first girlfriend was %s\n", (Object) getName());
```

Or (to create the requested array) even

```
System.out.printf("Your first girlfriend was %s\n", new Object[] {(Object) getName()} );
```

could help.

Comment: This isn't necessary for `printf`. Especially the second one: `System.out.printf` takes a `String` and a Varargs (so you don't need to package the array)

Comment: I think this is working around the symptom, rather than solving the root problem (which is likely that OP's IDE is compiling with a Java 1.4 compiler, which doesn't recognize var args).

Comment: @Quincunx I know. I just tried to interpret the question's error message and to react on it. If what you wrote is true in the case above, the error message would make no sense.

Comment: @ajp15243 Wouldn't a pre 1.5 compiler simply complain about printf as an undefined method?

Comment: @TAq Not if the method was actually defined. Unfortunately, the official archived Java 1.4 API docs are behind an Oracle login for download (I don't have time/motivation to get an account), so I can't check for sure, but given that `printf` is originally from C, and `System.out` has been around for a very long time in Java, I'd guess that the method still existed, just with different arguments (and I'd guess Java 1.4 compilers had a different way of figuring out overloaded method signatures, if that was even a thing back then). Since varargs weren't in Java 1.4, it would have used `Object[]`.

Comment: @ajp15243 I'd second this, but 1.4.2 seems to have had no printf method; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271148/cannot-resolve-symbol-error-for-printf) question. Anyway, the question seems to be answered.

Comment: @TAq Good point, maybe it doesn't. I'll probably go check the 1.4 docs out of curiosity at some point. However, I don't think this question is answered yet, as the OP hasn't replied in a while, and has not marked an answer as correct or provided his/her own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about my previous post saying I had the same problem, I didn't read the "before you post read this" dialog box that says don't do that. Well, after a lot of time looking around for the answer, I figured it out myself. In Preferences->Java->Compiler box, there is a button in the top left corner called "Configure Project Specific Settings...". Click it and either change the compliance level to >= Java 1.5, or turn it off. Boom, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to change the execution environment if it's not already java SE 1.8
it might be CDC or sth else , so u need to change it to  java SE 1.8
details in picture [1.expand ur project then 2.right click on JRE System Library and choose properties finally 3. if the environment is not java SE 1.8 ,change it to become so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhkn.jpg)